# Knitting pattern in the round

Tags: knitting

I’m following a pattern for an infinity scarf and it’s knit in the round. I can’t make sense of the cast-on portion of the pattern:

Cast-on and Setup rounds:
“CO 136 (4 repeats), CO 170 stitches (5 repeats)”

It then goes on to say “cast-on and join, then work bottom border...”

What does the “repeats” mean? How many stitches should I have total? I haven’t seen a pattern written like this before and google didn’t help. Thanks!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I understand it, the instruction offers 2 different sizes:

- Cast on 136 stitches if you want the pattern to repeat 4 times
- Cast on 170 stitches if you want the pattern to repeat 5 times

The pattern itself has 34 stitches.
34 x 4 = 136
34 x 5 = 170

When the instruction says "cast-on and join, then work bottom border..." it means "Choose one of the given sizes and cast on the corresponding number of stitches, then join and work bottom border..."